# How to export a Layer from a PDF into another PDF with PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I have two pdf file:

1. Layer.pdf
   [is a empty page with a layer called 'layer'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r19Qi.png)
2. Template.pdf
   [is a empty page without a layer but with two field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blhln.png)

How to export the "layer" from Layer.pdf file and "paste" into Template.pdf using Apache PDFBox? Thanks.!

Comment: Copying layers can be complicated, copying fields is less complicated. Thus, I'd propose you do it the other way around, adding the template fields to the layer pdf.